# Get name for the differentiating values in two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I need to compare to arrays (mysqli_fetch_array) from the same table fetching all columns.
I'm for-looping through and comparing all results.

```
$rowA = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = '$ID'"));
```

Performing UPDATE

```
$rowB = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = '$ID'"));

$len = count($rowA);
    for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
        if($rowA[$i] != $rowB[$i]){
            $msg .= [COLUMN NAME] . ' => ' . $rowB[$i];
        }

    }
```

How do I get the name of the column that differs?
I've tried array_keys() but the array it outputs isn't useful in ways I can come up with.

Comment: Replace the wildcard `*`, with the column name you want to compare in both queries.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I got this to work for me.

```
$arr = array_diff_assoc($rowA, $rowB);
$key = array_keys($arr);
$len = count($arr);
for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
         $msg .= $key[$i] . ' => ' . $rowB[$key[$i]];
}
```

Note: Added MYSQLI_ASSOC as resulttype for the mysqli_fetch_array function.